# How to check wether the XML tag contain value or not and perform the operation accordingly

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a XML like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
<Weight>15 kg</Weight>
<WeightUnits></WeightUnits>
</COLLECTION>
```

I want to perform KG to LBS

for that I have written :

```
<xsl:template match="Weight">
        <weight>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="translate(., translate(., '.0123456789', ''), '') div 0.45359237" />
        </weight>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
        <weightUnits>lbs</weightUnits>
    </xsl:template>
```

Everything is working fine:

My question is how can I check whether the data is present inside `<Weight>`

i.e if the value of `Weight` is present then and only then `weightUnits` contain LBS and if the `Weight` is empty  `weightUnits` also be empty.

Please help me with this scenario.

Comment: is it either empty or not?

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen : yes either it is empty of some value should be there like I specify in XML

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen : Either it is `<Weight>15 kg</Weight>` or `<Weight></Weight>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a solution that doesn't use any XSLT conditional operators at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="Weight">
    <weight><xsl:apply-templates/></weight>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Weight/text()[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:value-of
          select="translate(., translate(., '.0123456789', ''), '') div 0.45359237" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
     <weightUnits><xsl:apply-templates 
            select="../Weight[normalize-space()]" mode="lbs"/></weightUnits>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" mode="lbs">lbs</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<COLLECTION>
    <Weight>15 kg</Weight>
    <WeightUnits></WeightUnits>
</COLLECTION>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<COLLECTION>
    <weight>33.06933932773163</weight>
    <weightUnits>lbs</weightUnits>
</COLLECTION>
```

**when the same transformation is applied on the following XML document** (`<weight>` is empty):

```
<COLLECTION>
    <Weight></Weight>
    <WeightUnits></WeightUnits>
</COLLECTION>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<COLLECTION>
    <weight/>
    <weightUnits/>
</COLLECTION>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
   <weightUnits>
      <xsl:if test="../Weight!=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="'lbs'"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </weightUnits>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="WeightUnits">
   <weightUnits>
      <xsl:value-of select="if(../Weight!='') then('lbs') else('')"/>
   </weightUnits>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've added XSLT 1.0 solution, try using that one